# Help proving surjective functions under composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ be a nonempty set. Determine whether or not the following sets are closed under $F(A)$ under composition. Prove your answers. $$\{f\in F(A)|f\text{ is injective}\}$$ $$\{f\in F(A)|f\text{ is surjective}\}$$ $$\{f\in F(A)|f\text{ is bijective}\}$$

I have found a solution to the injective one and one if $f\in F(A,B)$ and $g\in F(B,C)$ where $f,g$ are surjective $\implies$ $fg$ is surjective. It is also apparent if I prove those two then if both $f,g$ are bijective then $fg$ would be bijective. I am just having trouble proving $\{f\in F(A)|f\text{ is surjective}\}$ since $F(A)$ is different than $F(A,B)$ and $F(B,C)$.

Comment: Can you define $F(A)$ and $F(A,B)$? Looks like $F(A)$ is the set of functions whose domain is $A$, and $F(A,B)$ is the set of functions $f:A\to B$, but I want to be sure

Comment: $F(A)$ is the set of functions whose domain is $A$.

Comment: Could you perhaps write a title that makes some sense? You have a lot of space to write a title. Don't be shy.

Comment: Is it possible that $F(A)$ is a shorthand for $F(A,A)$?

Comment: Looking at the textbook it would seem so as this is from a section on binary operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is well-founded: The second set is not closed under composition. Say $A=\{1\}$, and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(1)=0$. Then for $g:A\to \mathbb{R}$, $g\circ f$ is not defined.

If we restrict the second set further to functions whose image is $A$, the result does hold. Alternatively, if the image of $f$ is the domain of $g$, and $f$ and $g$ are both onto, then $g\circ f$ is onto.